# How to display null date values in DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datetimepicker, nullable

I've a datagrid where I'm displaying nullable date value. However, while saving the record on dataGrid, if I don't provide date it throws an error of 
{"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."}
Also, on xaml it doesn't even show the date if I pick a date.

**XAML**:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyDate">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <xcd:DateTimePicker  Value="{Binding MyDate, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource MinDateToNullConverter}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**Object**:

```
public DateTime? MyDate
    {
        get { return GetProperty(MyDateProperty); }
        set { SetProperty(MyDateProperty, value); }
    }
LoadProperty(MyDateProperty, dr.GetDateTime("MyDate"));
```

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDate", ReadProperty(MyDateProperty).ToDBNull());`

**Converter**:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(SmartDate), typeof(DateTime?))]
public class MinDateToNullConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(DateTime?) && value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            SmartDate theValue = value is SmartDate ? (SmartDate)value : new SmartDate(value.ToString());

            if (theValue == DateTime.MinValue)
                return null;
            else
                return theValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SqlDateTime error isn't related to wpf datagrid. check DAL code

Comment: I checked again. I do have it declared nullable and I also have ToDBNull() in my save stored procedure. Not sure what else it could be.